# Drupal always overwrite setting.php file

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am really new to Drupal and honestly I do not want to dig into it becuse my project is a short time one.

I've checked how should I set the settings.php, I did it, site is alive on localhost. After a while I am getting a page "Select an installation profile" and it wants to install the system from scratch.

I've checked, and my `settings.php` has been overwritten. Why is it and how can I avoid it.

Of course I tried to search at google for this, but it autocerrects me, the "overwrite" turned to "override" and I found no related results.

Comment: This is happening on your local machine? Not on a hosting provider?

Comment: Side note: You can tell Google not to autocorrect. "Including results for drupal settings.php override" says "Search only for drupal settings.php overwrite" below. Click that second link to get the non-corrected results.

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course I tried it, but in that case I've always get resutls `how to override settings.php` :) This is a local nginx, on ubuntu, PHP7.1

Comment: I don't know that any of us will have a hope of answering your question. What you describe isn't normal behavior, and I'd say it's more likely to be a mistake on your part (maybe you've got the folder in a Git repository and are inadvertently rolling it back) or something. Your best bet is probably going to be using [the audit log to monitor changes to the file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file) to tie it down to a particular time and process.

Comment: @ceejayoz The other interesting thing is that it is not the copy of `default.settings.php` I do not know where it came from. A clean `settings.php` withoout any code but comments how to use it.

Comment: Oh jesus, you are right. I did a `git reset --hard`. My fault, sorry. This is why I love SO :) More eyes sees more.

Comment: That'll do it, lol. Glad I could help you out.